# COM exception when sending email using Outlook interop

Tags: c#, outlook, com, office-interop

I'm trying to send email in my WPF app using following code.

```
private static void ApplicationDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
//Log the exception details here:            
e.Handled = true;

SendEmail();
}

private void SendEmail()
{
try

{
app = new Outlook.Application();

ns = app.GetNamespace("mapi");

ns.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

msg = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

...
...
...

await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    (msg as Outlook._MailItem).Send();
                    AppLogger.Log.Info("Email sent successfully!.");
                });
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
//Handle exception here.
}


finally
            {
                if (ns != null)
                {
                    ns.Logoff();
                }

                msg = null;
                ns = null;
                app = null;
            }
}
```

This code seems to work fine and emails are getting sent when deployed in other environments.
But today,when I was running code on my machine through Visua Studio,I got the following error at this line-->`(msg as Outlook._MailItem).Send();`

> Exception: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException:
>   COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be
>   used. The COM object was released while it was still in use on another
>   thread.

Wondering why did I get this error and what can I do to resolve it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a need to run as a task?   Do you see that if run just run synchronously?

Comment: COM does like multi thread. If you absolutely have to do it you need Thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the error means the COM object has already been released by your app.
Secondly, there is absolutely no reason to run `MailItem.Send` in a separate thread - the `Send` method is asynchronous anyway. Outlook simply marks the message as ready-for-submission and hands it off to the transport provider, which asynchronously sends it.